# How can i filter the files based on type?

Tags: windows

I need to list out the names of the files based on given type. Is there any tool to do that or is there any source code so that i can get the list of the files with given extension.

Example: If ".txt" is given then the output must contain list of all the text files in a specific directory.

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Is this a programming question?  If so, please say what language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find`, e.g.

```
% DIR=/foo/bar/blech
% SUFFIX=txt
% find "${DIR}" -name \*.${SUFFIX}
```

If you don't want to find matching files in subdirectories then change this last line to:

```
% find "${DIR}" -depth 1 -name \*.${SUFFIX}
```

If you are using Windows then you will need to install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) or similar before you can use `find`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.I need this filtering to be done in windows.Is there any way to do so

Comment: If you need an OS-spcific solution then you should really tag your question accordingly - I've done this for you now. Also, your question probably belongs on superuser.com. I've added a note to the answer for Windows users.

Comment: thanks.I am new to stackoverflow.so they may be mistakes in tagging questions.The problem is that i need to filter files from .iso image.Is there any tool that will do that or if it can be done in java?

Comment: @user369218: See my edit above - you can just install cygwin and use my original suggestion - no programming required.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the file names:

```
dir /b *.txt
```

If you want all the files in subdirectories:

```
dir /b/s *.txt
```

If you want to know more about "dir":

```
dir /?
```